# What is factory method in java?

Tags: java

I am a student and I had this question asked in my viva voce today and I hadn't even heard about it before.

I have searched over the internet about it and I always found the results to be very confusing and hard for me to interpret and understand.

Please, can any veteran present on this community explain it to me in a simple language.

I don't want to ask for any spoonfeeding but I tried my best to search for it and just couldn't understand a thing.

Please, explain it to me in a simple language(I am good at programming, but yet I found this concept hard to understand).

Comment: There are dozens of links on google...

Comment: *"Please, explain it to me in a simple language"* ... Hang on, I'll just go find my spoon!  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A factory method is a (usually static) method that serves as a method for creating (or better, providing) instances of a class.  It's an alternative for a simple constructor, or a full-on [Factory pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html).

The advantages of a factory method over a simple constructor are

- **Readability**:  `Car newCar = Car.duplicateOf(oldCar)` reveals intent far better than `Car newCar = new Car(oldCar)`
- **Possibility to return something not new**: `MonetaryAmount.valueOf(0)` could return a constant always used for zero.  You could also implement your own form of [interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).
- **Possibility to return a different class**: `Person.forAge(int age)` could return an instance of `Adult` or `Child` depending on the age passed in.

The advantage over a full factory pattern is that is simpler to implement and to use.  You only use a factory pattern if you need interchangeable implementations.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Answer (score 1):

Applicability: Use the `Factory Method` pattern when

- a class can't anticipate the class of objects it must create
- a class wants its subclasses to specify the objects it creates
- classes delegate responsibility to one of several helper subclasses, and you want to localize the knowledge of which helper subclass is the delegate.

[This link will surely help you](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns)